# CodeIgniter Active Record 'undefined property'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I get this

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_result::$result
>
> Filename: models/admin_model.php
>
> Line Number: 17

with this code

```
        $q = $this
        ->db
        ->where('username', $username)
        ->select('fname, lname')
        ->get('users');

    return $q->result;
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You're calling result as an object property. Result is a function:

```
return $q->result();
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html